# How to create toggle moving animation on scroll in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery animation like in the Dropbox. Here is my html and css:

HTML

```
 <div class='main-container'>
    <div class='logo-img-container'>
        <img class='logo-image' />
    </div>
    <div class='logo-header-container'>
        <h4 class="logo-header">This is logo header</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 .main-container{
      width:100%;
      text-align:center;
    }

    .logo-img-container{
      width:70px;
      display:inline-block;
    }

    .logo-header-container{
      width:70px;
      display:inline-block;
    }
```

What I want to do is when I scroll down, that logo image and logo header will be moved to the same position. Finally, it will be the logo image will stuck on the logo header, then logo header will be fade out. Then when I scroll up,logo image will move back to original position and logo header will appear and it will move back to its original position.

If I scroll down again, the same thing should be happened as the first scroll down. My jQuery code is below. When I initially scroll down, it is working as expected. But when I scroll up,nothing happens.

jQuery:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
      $(window).scroll(function(event){
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (st > lastScrollTop){
        if(lastScrollTop>0)
        {
            animateCombine()
        }
            } else {
                //up
                animateSplit()
            }
            lastScrollTop = st;
        });

    function animateSplit()
    {
        $( ".logo-image" ).stop().animate({
            marginRight: "50",
        }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });

         $('.logo-header').stop().animate({
            marginLeft: "50",
            opacity : "1"
        },500,function(){

        });
    }

    function animateCombine()
    {
        $( ".logo-image" ).stop().animate({
            marginLeft: "50",
        }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });

        $('.logo-header').stop().animate({
            marginRight: "50",
            opacity : "0"
        },500,function(){

        });
    }
```

What I exactly want to achieve is at the top of [this page](https://www.dropbox.com/). How can I achieve it?

Comment: If you don't have to use jquery then you should probably use [velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/). It makes animation like these very simple.

Comment: I need to use it with jquery

Comment: The Dropbox website is likely to have been redesigned since 2015, so this question is lacking a [mcve]. From the posting guidelines: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._